# Eliminar todos los datos cuando el usuario desinstala mi Aplicacion - Androd

Tags: android, android-studio, facebook-api

Hola buen día a todos.

Hace unas semanas lance una actualización de mi aplicación a la Play Store, y todo normal.
Mi sorpresa llega cuando algunos usuarios tienen un problema, el cual se presentaba cuando estos ya habían instalado la aplicación, pero la habían eliminado.
Entonces al momento de querer instalarla de nuevo no se ejecuta de manera en la que debería.

En mi app hago uso de sesiones por parte de facebook, entonces si estos ya habían iniciado sesión, ya podían entrar directamente sin siquiera pasar por el Login (Ya que valido primero que deben de estar "Logeados" para poder pasar a el MainActivity).
Esto hace que se salte ciertos pasos necesarios en la aplicación.

Antes de intentar cambiar código en mi aplicación, me preguntaba si existe una manera en la cual al momento de eliminar mi aplicación también se eliminen todos los archivos temporales y no temporales que esta género.

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola es normal pensar que cuando uno desinstala una app lo referido a esa app se elimina incluyendo el SharedPreference y datos temporales. Pero en la practica muchas veces pareciera no ser así y esto pasa porque Android tiene un sistema de backup. Cuando haces un update de la app a una version mas nueva o cambias de telefono, lo mas seguro es que la app recurra al backup para recuperar los datos anteriores y que el usuario no pierda nada. Para nosotros que estamos programando y probando cosas esto puede ser muy molesto, yo personalmente uso un metodo para limpiar mi sharedpreference cada vez que necesito probar algunas cosas donde se que me puede traer problemas, por ejemplo cuando pruebo el login.

Una solucion para que no te pase en teoria es setear allowBackup en false dentro del manifest.

```
<application ...
   android:allowBackup="false">
   ...
</application>
```

Sinembargo muchos dispositivos no toman en cuenta que le pongas false al allowBackup y te guardaran los datos de todas formas. Asi que para estar mas seguro tambien podes usar `fullBackupContent='false'` en el manifest.

Si bien esto puede funcionar y evitaria que cambies el codigo yo te recomiendo que cambies el codigo para que soporte el camino en el que aun hay datos guardados. Tu aplicacion seria mas robusta, no dependeria de los caprichos de las distintas versiones de Android y las adaptaciones que le realizan los fabricantes. Ademas, para el usuario final siempre es mas comodo que la app recuerde su sesion sin problemas.

Comment: Muchas gracias campeon. Justo lo que buscaba. :)